# syntax for EXEC stored procedure for update query

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am getting follow error while executing store procedure using SQLSRV.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
          [0] => 42000 
          [SQLSTATE] => 42000 
          [1] => 102 
          [code] => 102 
          [2] => [Microsoft]
          [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server] 
          [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '='. 
          [message] => 
               [Microsoft]
                   [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
                      [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'r'. ) 
                           [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 8180 [code] => 8180 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. ) )

$tsql_callSP = "EXEC usp_u_social_twitter var_tweet = ?, var_screenname = ?, var_maxid = ?, var_link = ?, varid = ?";
```

The code that I am using is as below

```
$tsql_callSP = "EXEC usp_u_social_twitter var_tweet = ?, var_screenname = ?, var_maxid = ?, var_link = ?, varid = ?";

$stmt3 = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $tsql_callSP, array(&$tweet, &$screenname, &$maxid, &$link, &$id));
```

What am I missing here for syntax. These variable names listed here are not the real ones.. But I am missing some syntax here...

The code works if I give normal update query... with same variable name...

Please help me... Thanks in advance...
Whatz the correct syntax for this... Couldn't find sample program even here in stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "@" at the beginning of the parameters of the stored procedure. It should be:

```
$tsql_callSP = "EXEC usp_u_social_twitter @var_tweet = ?, @var_screenname = ?, @var_maxid = ?, @var_link = ?, @varid = ?";
```